# three levels select statement in LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to get data for a specific county ID using LINQ statement,
the query in SQL looks like this :

```
Select  Ads_ComputersID, AdTitle, AdDesc, CityID, CategoryID, Price
From [dbo].[Ads_Computers] where CityID in ( Select CityID from [dbo].[Cities] where [StateID] in (select StateID from [dbo].[States] where CountryID=10))
```

since I am still new to LINQ can you please help me to achieve this , and what is better to use LINQ or stored procedure with datasets?

another SQL way:

```
SELECT  A.Ads_ComputersID, A.AdTitle, A.AdDesc, A.CityID, A.CategoryID, A.Price
FROM [dbo].[Ads_Computers] A
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Cities] C ON A.CityID=C.CityID
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[States] S ON S.StateID = C.StateID
WHERE S.CountryID=10
```

thanks and best regards

Comment: why not use join with tables  instead of inner queries with in ?

Comment: i am trying to make it simple, I can make it on SQL but I am not sure if it can be done suing LINQ

Comment: @Hakunamatata Just updated the question :)

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think. For example, where *exactly* are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is Entity Framework, you can make your data query tasks much easier (especially if you are new to LINQ) and basically forget about joins if you describe your data relations using the so called [navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx).

Once you have them, a query like the one if question would be simple as that:

```
var query = db.Ads_Computers.Where(c => c.City.State.Country.CountryID == 10);
```

(of course you can add `Select` if you want to get only a specific fields).

Answer (score 1):

You could so something like below which converts inner query in LINQ.

**Note :** I have not tested it so there may be bug.

```
Select  Ads_ComputersID, AdTitle, AdDesc, CityID, CategoryID, Price
From [dbo].[Ads_Computers] 
where CityID in ( Select CityID from [dbo].[Cities] where [StateID] in (select StateID from [dbo].[States] where CountryID=10))
```

LINQ

```
var innermostQuery = from s in db.States where s.CountryID = 10 select s.CityId;
var innerQuery = from c in db.Cities where innemostQuery.Contains(c.StateId) select c.CityID;

var result = from x in db.Ads_Computers  where innerQuery.ToList().Contains(x.CityIS) select x;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from d in entities.Ads_Computers
            from c in entities.Cities.Where(cid => cid.CityID == d.CityID).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from s in entities.States.Where(st => st.StateID == c.StateID).DefaultIfEmpty()
            where st.CountryID = 10
            select new 
            {
                d.Ads_ComputersID, 
                d.AdTitle, 
                d.AdDesc, 
                d.CityID, 
                d.CategoryID, 
                d.Price
            };
```

Hope this helps!